# Unlabled app entries appearing in battery history. Suspicious?

Tags: processes, battery-history

This morning I noticed weird untitled entries in my battery history, which I'd never seen before.  I'm also not sure why some rows were not showing the percentages. (When tapped on, the entry detail views show the percentages.) The entries have the same code/gear icon as the Android OS entry:

[image: entries] [image: detail] [image: same icon as Android OS]
<sup>entries / detail / same icon as Android OS (click images for larger variant)</sup>

These aren't appearing in the last-hour view now, so it appears to be something that launched earlier, and then stopped. "Force stop" and "report" are grayed out in the detail views.

Is this suspicious? Is there some way of checking these further?

This is on a non-rooted HTC One M9 running Android 6.0

Comment: My first thought were system processes; but though the icon would fit that assumption, they'd at least carry a process id (numerical), and rarely show up in packs like that. So it's at least strange. Are you familiar with ADB, so you could make a dump of battery stats (`adb dumpsys batterystats`) to investigate?

Comment: Just tried "adb shell dumpsys batterystats > output.txt". Gives a hell of a lot of lines... I guess I would need something like https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian to make more sense of it?

Comment: That might definitely help. Sorry, but I've never digged into battery stats, I just know they are there …

Answer (score 0):

Did you install any app from Unknown sources,  i.e. downloading the apk and then installing? If yes, Can you see these apps in the Apps section in Settings of your phone? And if yes, is the uninstall button active?

If not, this might be due to the administrator privilages this app has got. First, you need to remove administrator privilages from the app. i would recommend to download ES File Manager from Play Store and finding that app. Then try to uninstall these apps and see if these really have administrator privilages. And, if they have, remove them using ES File Manager only and then, uninstall the applications.

Hope, this works fine for you. Basically, these apps are downloaded with the .apk file you download from the unknown resources, get themself administrator privilages and start showing ads on your device.

Comment: The only app I've ever done through unknown sources was ABP, because Google kicked it out of the the store ( https://techcrunch.com/2013/03/14/adblock-plusresponds-to-google-play-bar/ ). Oh and years ago on another phone I installed a beta version of a navigation app called "Metr0" that's been developed since Palm Pilots and Symbian phones. Otherwise, I stay away from unknown sources for the obvious reasons.

Comment: Well, there is a possibility that when you downloaded ABP, you downloaded a bunch of malware with that as well. It is very common with ad-supported websites. Check if the apps are present in **Safe Mode** as well and try uninstalling the apps